# No suitable method found for thenReturn

Tags: java, mockito, amazon-kinesis

I am new to java and mockito, trying to mock my

```
//kinesisClient is of type KinesisAsyncClient
PutRecordResponse result = kinesisClient.putRecord(putRecordRequest).get();
```

like below:

```
KinesisAsyncClient kinesisClient = mock(KinesisAsyncClient.class);
PutRecordResult res = mock(PutRecordResult.class);
res.setShardId("shard-12345");
when(kinesisClient.putRecord(any()).get())
                .thenReturn(res);
```

it's giving

```
error: no suitable method found for thenReturn(PutRecordResult)
.thenReturn(res);
```

I tried

```
KinesisAsyncClient kinesisClient = mock(KinesisAsyncClient.class);
final PutRecordResult res = new PutRecordResult();
res.setShardId("shard-12345");
when(kinesisClient.putRecord(any()).get())
                .thenReturn(res);
```

but same error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You cannot do `when(client.putRecord(any()).get())`, you can only do `when(client.putRecord(any()))`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that the thenReturn method expects a PutRecordResponse object, but you are passing in a PutRecordResult object.

To fix this error, you should create a PutRecordResponse object and set its sequenceNumber and shardId fields to appropriate values, then use it in the thenReturn method like this:

```
KinesisAsyncClient kinesisClient = mock(KinesisAsyncClient.class);
PutRecordResponse res = mock(PutRecordResponse.class);
when(res.getSequenceNumber()).thenReturn("12345");
when(res.getShardId()).thenReturn("shard-12345");
when(kinesisClient.putRecord(any())).thenReturn([PutRecordResponse type]);

// Call the method that uses the mocked KinesisAsyncClient
```

Here, we are mocking the PutRecordResponse object and setting its sequenceNumber and shardId fields to appropriate values. Then, we are using the thenReturn method to return a CompletableFuture that completes with the mocked PutRecordResponse object when the putRecord method is called on the mocked KinesisAsyncClient.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. What is exactly `[PutRecordResponse type]`? Can you give me an example of `thenReturn` with a return value?

Comment: It's failing for `error: cannot find symbol when(res.getSequenceNumber()).thenReturn("12345");` and also `getShardId`.